# changing the Background color also affect text color

Tags: android, android-color

I have a table made of buttons and when the Background color of the button is changing so does the text color.

Note - The text on every view is the black dot as you can in the images below.

---

**For example**, when I am changing the color for some of the views to blue it looks like this (the text is white):

[image]

**The problem start when the background color is white, causing the text to disappear (the text is no longer visible inside the blue area) :**

[image]

---

### The Question

How can I prevent the text from changing its color when the view background color is changing?

### My code

Whenever a button is clicked this line is getting called to change its background color:

```
 cell.setBackgroundColor(currentColor) //cell = the view , currentColor = the background color
```

Comment: Any reason for the downvote? If you downvoted my question please let me know what's wrong with it so I can improve my future questions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know why the text color kept changing but I just changed the text color of that view as well when he got clicked and that solved the problem:

```
 cell.setOnClickListener { //cell = the view
        cell.setTextColor(Color.BLACK)      
        cell.setBackgroundColor(currentColor)
    }
```